# How is the 'level=' argument of 'predict' function justified?

Tags: r, statistics, predict

I am new to R. I have written an example code as follows:

```
model <- lm(Height~Age,data = class)
predict(model,data.frame(Age=35),interval = "confidence",level = .95)
predict(model,data.frame(Age=35),interval = "confidence",level = .99)
predict(model,data.frame(Age=35),interval = "confidence",level = .90)
```

With the results:

```
predict(model,data.frame(Age=35),interval = "confidence",level = .95)
       fit      lwr      upr
1 69.77465 53.73338 85.81591
> predict(model,data.frame(Age=35),interval = "confidence",level = .99)
       fit      lwr     upr
1 69.77465 45.46979 94.0795
> predict(model,data.frame(Age=35),interval = "confidence",level = .90)
       fit     lwr      upr
1 69.77465 57.0357 82.51359
```

Now my confusion is:
when confidence level is increasing from 90% to 99% the fit range is increasing but to my knowledge in statistics when confidence level increases(i.e. error margin decreases) the range should decrease.
I am sure I am wrong somewhere. Plz help

Comment: If you are 99% confident that the true value is between 45.47 and 94.08, what happens to your confidence when that band is narrowed? Let's go to an extreme ... how confident are you that the true value is between 65.1 and 65.2? Most likely a very low confidence. From that, understand that increasing confidence results in a wider interval.

Comment: The argument `level` is not defining your confidence in the model: it's defining the confidence that the prediction will contain the true value (given the prior data and model parameters).

Comment: Make sure you have the frequentist definition of a confidence interval in mind when thinking about this: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158570/interpretation-of-confidence-interval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not. If the randomness of data remains unchanged, you will only be more and more confident of your interval estimation as the interval gets larger.

If this is still unclear to you, consider the most illustrative example. You want to propose an interval `(-a, a)` to contain a random sample of `N(0, 1)`. Now, if `a = 1`, the interval only has 67% chance to contain such a random sample, but if `a = 3`, your confidence increases to 99%.